# Why .inf file in visuals studio 2022 is different

Tags: kernel, driver, inf, minifilter

I am trying to develop a file system filter and I trying to install in my vm but it does not have serveral information like service name ,driver name idk that it is not available to any one or it is not showing to me only?

Is we need to manually edit the .inf file or it will automatically generate with any settings change?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.